# Unity: Opacity over Distance with Surface Shaders

Tags: unity, shaders, surface-shader

I want to tweak the alpha value based on the distance to the camera. But I see no way of passing the vertex position on to the surface function using surface shaders. Not a problem with frag shader.

It's for fading out vegetation and creating LOD systems.

```
Shader "asdf" {
SubShader {
    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf StandardSpecular alphatest:_Cutoff addshadow vertex:vert
     
    struct v2f {
        float4 pos : TEXCOORD1;
    };

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_Maintex;
    };
        
    v2f vert (inout appdata_base v) {
        v2f o;
        o.pos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, v.vertex);
        return o;
    }

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandardSpecular o) {
        //Need vertex or pixel distance here:
        //float dist = length(v2f.pos.xyz - _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz);
        //o.Alpha = saturate(50/dist);
    }
    ENDCG
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask for `worldPos` in your `Input` structure ([as documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SurfaceShaders.html)):

```
struct Input {
    float2 uv_Maintex;
    float3 worldPos;
};

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandardSpecular o) {        
    float dist = length(IN.worldPos - _WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz);
    o.Alpha = saturate(50/dist);
}
```